# Scrapy: Extracting data from an html tag that uses div, span, then class

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm unaware of the methods to dig through the layers to get to my data

This is what I've gotten to but it returns a lot of gibberish along with the data I require.

```
response.css('#info1').extract_first()
```

```
<div id="info1" class="generalized" style="width: auto;">
<strong>Locales:</strong> 
    <span><a href="?w=series&amp;a=AA&amp;a=OC&amp;a=TA&amp;a=MA&amp;g=Chicago" class="discreet">Chicago</a></span>
</div>
```

I would like to extract 'Chicago' but I'm getting everything else.

Thanks :D

Comment: Try `response.css('#info1 strong span a::text').get()` or even `response.css('#info1 a::text').get()`

Comment: Thank you. I just realized how newbie this question was as I could have Googled it better. Thank you again :D